# The maximum flow from the source to the sink of a graph is equal to the ____________________.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm doing a study guide for an exam right now, and I've filled every problem out but the one in the title.

I know how to calculate max flow using the minimum cut method, but I actually don't know what to put in the blank. I feel like it's obvious, but I can't find the answer in my book or elsewhere online.

Comment: The total weight of the edges on the minimum cut?

Comment: See here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem

Comment: I'm guessing that is correct then. I was thinking it was a short formula or what not, because all the other fill in the section were formulas. Was trying to make sure I wasn't missing something important! Thank you!